# XSLT: in a <p> element, how to replace a line break (<br/>) with successive <alinea> element?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, line-breaks

I am trying to transform a `<p>` element with `<br/>` elements within into several `<alinea>subtext</alinea>`. For instance :

```
<p>subtext<br/>some more text<br/> some more subtext</p>
```

From the previous `<p>` I was hoping to simply replace all `<br/>` into `</alinea><alinea>` since the template for `<p>` opens a `<alinea>` element already.

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <para><alinea><xsl:apply-templates/></alinea></para>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="br">
    </alinea><xsl:apply-templates/><alinea>
</xsl:template>
```

But it is doesn't validate.

Expected result :

```
<para>
   <alinea>
     subtext
   </alinea>
   <alinea>
     some more text
   </alinea>
   <alinea>
     some more subtext
   </alinea>
 </para>
```

Comment: Can you please provide input XML?

Comment: done in the question. thanks.

Comment: What if input XML contains other elements, e.g: `<p>subtext<br/>some more text<br/> some more subtext <div>abc</div></p>`?

Comment: seems to be working, I would just add a template for `<div>` : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMD/1

Comment: Questions like this should be tagged "xslt 1.0" or "xslt 2.0". The solutions using 2.0 constructs are generally much easier, but not everyone (sadly) has access to an XSLT 2.0 (or 3.0) processor.

Comment: it is xslt 2.0 indeed. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy to do in XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <para>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="br">
            <alinea>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[not(self::br)]" />
            </alinea>   
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </para>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh2Q

Answer (score 1):

Prob you can use something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="p">
    <para>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </para>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <aline>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </aline>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="br"/>

  <xsl:template match="div">
    <blockquote>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </blockquote>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I anticipate your solution will put `<alinea>` element everywhere in the text. For instance, a text with emphase `<p>Hello <em>World</em></p>` will result in `<para><alinea>Hello</alinea><alinea>World</alinea></para>`.

Answer (score -1):

I found a (dirty?) way to replace `<br>` with `</alinea><alinea>` :

```
  <xsl:template match="br">
     <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes">
        &lt;/alinea&gt;&lt;alinea&gt;
     </xsl:value-of>
  </xsl:template>
```

Anything prettier ?

Comment: I would be happy to have explanation about the down-vote, cause the solution works perfectly ! :)

Comment: I downvote any answer that uses DOE to create markup.